# Track PHP memory usage from command line

Tags: php

I can use both `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');` in the file and `php -d memory_limit=512M` from the command line, but can also trace memory usage from terminal?

I know I can use `memory_get_usage()` inside a PHP file, but how to trace it from the command line?

Comment: `php -r "var_dump(memory_get_usage());"`

Comment: @Justinas If I'll add `watch -n 1` I will see how usage is changing while during the runtime. Is there a better way to find out?

Comment: `php -r "var_dump(memory_get_usage());"` will not help you, because it `Returns the amount of memory allocated to PHP`. You need to pass `true` as [parameter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage) to see the real used memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
$ watch -n 5 'php -r "var_dump(memory_get_usage());"'
```

This will watch every 5 seconds the memory state

**Or** may be you can use the 'ps' tool:

```
$ ps -F -C php-cgi
```

Output:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
http     10794 10786  0  4073   228   0 Jun09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

RSS is the Real-memory (resident set) size in kilobytes of the process.

Comment: I think this solution is more robust one than mine

Answer (score 0):

The solution I was looking for with a **simple output** is

```
watch -n 5 'php -r "echo (string) memory_get_usage(true)/pow(10, 6);"'
```

Will return **how many MB** the PHP process is using.

```
2.097152
```

---

**NOTICE:** Solution like `ps -F -C php-cgi` on macOS machines will fail with

```
ps: illegal option -- F
```